# Editor for groovy and grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, syntax-highlighting, text-editor

Is there any editor like notepad++ for groovy or
any editor that support .groovy highlighting.
Please help with link and name.

Comment: Intellij IDEA has very good support for Grails.

Comment: Spring source tool suite works great for me, and its free

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) has great [Groovy and Grails support](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/groovy_grails.html); the free community edition [doesn't support Grails](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

[Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) is my current favorite cross-platform editor. AFAIK it doesn't have a GSP-specific mode, but (a) does have JSP, and (b) is customizable. It uses TextMate bundles, Groovy and Grails available:

- [Groovy bundle](https://github.com/textmate/groovy.tmbundle)
- [Grails bundle](https://github.com/textmate/groovy-grails.tmbundle)
- [Sublime-specific Grails](https://github.com/osoco/sublimetext-grails)

Comment: Sublime 3 has now package for groovy language.

Comment: Sadly syntax highlighting is still bugged in multiple ways in Sublime 3 https://i.imgur.com/Q7LhzEg.png

Answer (score 29):

You mentioned NotePad++ in your question. If you want Groovy syntax highlighting in NotePad++, download the user defined language file from

<strike>http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=User_Defined_Language_Files</strike> 
http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=User_Defined_Language_Files

and add it to the installation directory.

Comment: Instead of adding the userDefineLang_Groovy.xml to the installation directory, you can also select the "Language | Define your language..." menu item in Notepad++. In the dialog you can click the Import button, select the definition file and close the dialog again.

Comment: Link is down so here is new link http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/commun/userDefinedLang/userDefineLang_Groovy.xml

Answer (score 5):

An amazing IDE is [STS](http://www.springsource.org/sts) — powered by Springsource, based on Eclipse and stand-alone. Free, ready to deploy (with a dedicated plugin). 
I use GGTS devoted to Groovy and Grails : free IDE based on Eclipse delivered by SpringSource.

Answer (score 3):

see http://groovy.codehaus.org/IDE+Support and http://groovy.codehaus.org/Other+Plugins

Update: The useful page is currently:
http://groovy-lang.org/ides.html

Answer (score 2):

Guess what [sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/) has great support for groovy. This is not IDE, its just a text editor

Answer (score 1):

Vim/gVim has Groovy highlighting if you're looking to kick it oldschool.